# Need to get required http post

Tags: api, powershell, http

I am following Huddle Api instructions to get the Access Token. I am using powershell to post the method which is as follows:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.huddle.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=s6BhdRkqt&redirect_uri=MyAppServer.com/receiveAuthCode&code=i1WsRn1uB1
```

Powershell Command which I am using is:

```
$body = { '@grant_type' = 'authorization_code'; client_id = 'xxxxx';
           redirect_uri = 'myAppServer.com'; code = '123abcdef' } 

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "login.huddle.com" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Method Post
```

This works and I get the response of "200 OK" and also shows the activation of Access Token. How would I retrieve the Access Token number. For example, I need the output as they mentioned in instruction which is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store

{
 "access_token":"S1AV32hkKG",
 "expires_in":300,
 "refresh_token":"8xLOxBtZp8"
}
```

I think it has something to do ContentType. So I did try, "application/Json" but that was not it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong cmdlet. Since you mentiond getting back values for StatusCode, Content, RawContent, etc, that tells us that you're using Invoke-WebRequest.  This cmdlets awesome...but not for working with APIs, which are commonly REST formatted and use JSON.  `IWR` can handle the request but you have to dig into the `$Response.Content` and convert from JSON.

Instead of Invoke-WebRequest, try using Invoke-RestMethod. It's likely that you are getting the AccessCode returned, but as a JSON formatted property. `Invoke-RestMethod` will natively parse and convert JSON into PowerShell objects.  You can just sub it in for `Invoke-WebRequest` and it should *just work*.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "login.huddle.com" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Method Post -body $body
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I really appreciate it. Its just the response does not the value i think or maybe its there with a different name. I have contacted Huddle over this. Hopefully will get an answer from them. Again Thanks

Comment: I'm going to look over the API documentation I think I see the problem. I'll update this later on today

Comment: Did you already register for an API token?  (Have to send an e-mail to them, as listed here: https://github.com/Huddle/huddle-apis/wiki/OAuth%20Integration)

Comment: @FoxDeplay Yes, that was like the first step. That I already did. Anyhow, I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. The URI was supposed to be login.huddle.com/token. With this I was able to get the Access token. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you use Invoke-RestMethod you can set the response when making the call

`$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "login.huddle.com" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Method Post"`

then `$response.access_token` or `$response.expires_in` or `$response.refresh_token`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. In response, I am not getting these fields. Only available  fields are: Status Code, Content, RawContent, Forms, Headers, Images, Forms, Links ParsedHtml.

Comment: Is there any other way, I can retrieve the required information?

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod performs a web request and then convets from the response back from JSON into a PowerShell object.  It's meant to be used against Rest endpoints where the other fields are overhead.  Use Invoke-WebRequest if you want ParsedHtml, StatusCode, etc.