# How to Post Request with Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

How would I use `Invoke-WebRequest` to post all these parameters

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.huddle.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=s6BhdRkqt&redirect_uri=MyAppServer.com/receiveAuthCode&code=i1WsRn1uB
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's how to convert that body into one which PowerShell can interpret.

```
$body = @{grant_type='authorization_code'
      client_id='s6BhdRkqt'
      redirect_uri='MyAppServer.com/receiveAuthCode'
      code='i1WsRn1uB'}
$contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri yourUrl -body $body -ContentType $contentType
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what I was doing but havent achieved what I am looking for. Could you please look this post. Havent got any answer to it. Its just I dont see the access token in response. Thanks again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707868/need-to-get-required-http-post/41707939#41707939

Comment: Added a comment to that post but the TLDR is that you should use Invoke-RestMethod instead of Invoke-WebRequest.  With all the same params it should `Just work`.

Comment: Thank you, i was using [PSCustomObject]@{name='bla'}, and this content type does not like a body that is a PSCustomObject!

Comment: Understandable, @Omzig, as PowerShell muscle memory kind of trains us to always prefix a hashtable with `[psCustomObject]`.  However the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlets rely on us, the authors, to convert our `-Body` value to the right content type.  In the modern Web that is almost always JSON for most APIs, but sometimes not.  Contrast that with  `Invoke-Restmethod`, which assumes you're working with Rest and so always converts the body value into JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like that

```
$loginPage = Invoke-WebRequest "http:\\website.com\" # invoke login form page
$loginForm = $loginPage.Forms[0] # Get the form to fill
$loginForm.fields["userName"] = "usrnm" # fill the username
$loginForm.fields["password"] = "psswd" # fill the password
$loginPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http:\\website.com\") -Method POST -Body $loginForm.fields # Post the form to log-in
```