# Trying to make a API call to get token

Tags: json, powershell, api, http, type-conversion

Below is the code I was trying to make a API call for a token. Seems like the x-www-form-urlencoded is causing the 401 unauthorized while converting to body.what is the standard process for converting the body to x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class ServerCertificateValidationCallback
    {
        public static void Ignore()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                delegate
                (
                    Object obj, 
                    X509Certificate certificate, 
                    X509Chain chain, 
                    SslPolicyErrors errors
                )
                {
                    return true;
                };
        }
    }
"@
[ServerCertificateValidationCallback]::Ignore();

$header = @{
 "content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 "accept"="application/json"
}

$APICURL= "myurl" 

$json = @{ "grant_type"="access"
         "client_id" = "xyz"
         "client_secret" = "abc"
        "scope" = "one"}


         $body = $json | ConvertTo-Json
          $response =Invoke-Restmethod -Uri $APICURL -Method Post -Headers $header -Body $body
```

Comment: Content-Type by default in a POST is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I would remove that from the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set Content-Type to x-www-form-urlencoded, but you're supplying JSON. JSON is pretty common as a body type, so I'd first try updating your Content-Type to be *application/json* unless you're certain the spec calls for x-www-form-urlencoded.

If the latter, you may want to check out this question: [How to Post Request with Invoke-WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746097/how-to-post-request-with-invoke-webrequest)

Comment: Instead of JSON how can supply x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: Is there a way that i can convert my JSON body to x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: If the link I provided isn't working for you, you can use this: https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/05/26/encodedecode-your-url-with-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

Change content-type to application/json.